# returning array of string from function not working as expected

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to pass an array of strings to a function, make some changes to it inside this function, and pass it back to `main()` and print it to see the changes. It is not working as expected. Please tell me where I'm going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

//don't forget to declare this function
char** fun(char [][20]);

int main(void)
{
    char strar[10][20] = { {"abc"}, {"def"}, {"ghi"}, {""},{""} }; //make sure 10 is added
    char** ret; //no need to allocate anything for ret, ret is just a placeholder, allocation everything done in fun
    int i = 0;

    ret = fun(strar);
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        printf("[%s] ",ret[i]);

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

//don't forget function has to return char** and not int. (Remember char**, not char*)
char** fun(char strar[][20])
{
    int i = 0;
    char** ret;
    ret = malloc(sizeof(void*)); //sizeof(void*) is enough, it just has to hold an address 

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        ret[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(ret[i],strar[i]);
    }

    strcpy(ret[3],"fromfun");

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Please define "not working as expected".

Comment: @Marvin, this is the output I get [��] [def] [ghi] [fromfun]

Comment: And what output would you expect?

Comment: @Marvin, I was expecting  [abc] [def] [ghi] [fromfun]

Comment: 'it just has to hold an address'...... 'ret[i] ='

Comment: @MartinJames yay beat you by 45 sec... :-)

Comment: AKA 'arrays are not pointers'

Comment: @SouravGhosh - meh, my net is slow today:)

Comment: Should have used a more minimal example

Comment: lol - @SouravGhosh didn't get the accept anyway, even though first to the correct answer:(

Comment: @MartinJames What to do.. :'( Today's not really my day. Did you notice the serial DV on me earlier today? (weep)

Comment: Note: Do not use `void *` without actual need. The correct  way is `ret = malloc(sizeof(*ret))`. This will infer the type from the variable, thus always have the correct size. The second best `ret = malloc(sizeof(char *))`. Note: I intentionally omitted the required multiplier. Also note: `sizeof(char)` is _defined_ to yield  `1`. I.e., it will never yield anything different, so it is nonsense to use.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Fine, thanks, hope you're fine, too. Ok, got it. Yes, sorry, I did not hav a closer look at it. Anyway, it might help, if as many people comment on that as possible.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Read the post now. See above

Comment: @Olaf Yes, sure sir. Absolutely perfect, no issues. Take my comment in this way, I was trying to get a _free_ review of my answer from you by pointing you to it. Anyways, I ^-ed your comment already. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh - no  I didn't notice but, anyway, it was your turn to suffer:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure that you allocate the full array of pointers for **ret** array.

```
//don't forget function has to return char** and not int. (Remember char**, not char*)
char** fun(char strar[][20])
{
 int i = 0;
 char** ret;
 ret = malloc(sizeof(void*) * 5); //sizeof(void*) is enough, it just has to hold an address 

 for(i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
  ret[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));
  strcpy(ret[i],strar[i]);
 }

 strcpy(ret[3],"fromfun");

 return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The major issue, as I can see is the memory overrun.

You allocate memory to hold one element

```
 ret = malloc(sizeof(void*));
```

but, you're putting 5 elements.

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    ret[i] = malloc(20 * sizeof(char));....
```

It is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
to access beyond the allocated memory.

The memory allocation to `ret` should look like

```
 ret = malloc(5 * sizeof(char *));
```

or

```
 ret = malloc(5 * sizeof*ret); //portable
```

To elaborate the changes made

- Allocate 5 times the size of a single element, as we're going to store 5 elements.
- Strictly speaking, as the `ret` is of type `char **`, we need to use `char *` while calculating the size to be allocated for `ret`, not a `void *`.
- The change towards using `sizeof *ret` makes the code more robust, as in future, if the type of `ret` get changed to some other type, you don't need to repeat the type changes in this allocation, as the allocation would depend on the type of `*ret`, anyway.

Note: FWIW, the parenthesis around the argument to `sizeof` is required only in case of the argument being a data type, like `sizeof(int)`. In case of using a variable name as argument, the parenthesis is optional, i.e., both `sizeof(*ptr)` and `sizeof *ptr` are both perfectly valid and legal.

That said,

1. Always check for the success of `malloc()` before using the returned pointer
2. In `C`, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`. Using the same as a multiplier is redundant.

Comment: +1. I like it as you actually explain, not just provide code. Two small additions, if I may suggest: Why the change from `void *` to `char *`, and I'd put more emphasis on `*ret`. A personal note: I prefer to use function-style of `sizeof` actually; that is more consistent - but that is really just my personal preference, your code is ok as-is!)

Comment: @Olaf Thank you for your valuable input. I tried to clarify, please review once more. :-)

Comment: Perfectly. If I had asked I had accepted your answer. (how polite we are today:-). I just took the freedom to add two spaces.

Comment: @Olaf Fine, fine. Good to hear that. :-)